# Set freehand pen tools Canvas weight and height relative to element and responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am using WebSocket to transmit a freehand draw from my PC to a remote PC, Once drawing commence I get a different positioning of the stroke on different screen sizes, but I need it to align to the same position on both screen sizes. I hope I'm able to better express my question for your understanding. Below is the code sample of my attempt

```
const canvas = canvasRef.current;
canvas.width = videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width;
canvas.height = videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height;
canvas.style.width = `${videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`;
canvas.style.height = `${videoContainer.getBoundingClientRect().height}px`;

const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.lineCap = "round";
context.strokeStyle = "#FF9900";
context.lineWidth = 5;
contextRef.current = context;

canvasRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", ({ offsetX, offsetY }) => {
  if (!isDrawing) {
    return;
  }
  var x = offsetX;
  var y = offsetY;

  contextRef.current.beginPath();
    contextRef.current.moveTo(x, y);
      contextRef.current.lineTo(x, y);
    contextRef.current.stroke();
});
```

How do I make `offsetX` and `offsetY` relative to the remote element container because I keep track of `offsetX` and `offsetY` in an array and pass it to be redrawn on the remote PC using a WebSocket

Comment: I think you should be able to solve your question after reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Yeah thanks, the article was on track but the issue I have here is to make a relative mouse draw position of offsetX and  offsetY equal in the different container of different screen sizes (Remote and Local PC )

Comment: Once you get the bounding box of the container, you can do quick arithmetic to unify different screen sizes and basically pass information like x at 30% from left y at 60% from top etc. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around it